# Rails app boot delay, could be a Docker issue, but unsure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, docker, docker-compose

I'm in the process of switching to developing my app in a Docker scenario rather than a Vagrant one.

I've got Docker configured etc and my docker-compose file and it all runs but when I run a command in the container such as `docker-compose run app rake db:create`, it takes ages to run. At least a full two minutes before I see any output, it does successfully run the commands but takes ages of looking like it's not doing anything before I see output.

I have no idea what it could be doing or what is holding things up. Because of this i'm unsure what files to post here in order to help people to decipher what is going on.

If you have any ideas or want me to post code or specific files then let me know and i'll get them added on here.

It's really frustrating and would like to get this sorted so I can get on with building my app.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - PG_PASSWORD=secret
      - PG_HOST=pg
      - PG_PORT=5432
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - PG_PASSWORD=secret

volumes:
  pg-data:
```

It's odd, I start up the containers and the app one just does not do anything for a good two to three minutes. Eventually I start to get output like so:

```
app_1  | => Booting Puma
app_1  | => Rails 5.2.1 application starting in development
app_1  | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
app_1  | Puma starting in single mode...
app_1  | * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
app_1  | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
app_1  | * Environment: development
app_1  | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
app_1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I've just removed everything from the `config` directory and reloaded the app, then adding back each file it complains about one at a time one by one. It started to complain about `environment.rb` missing, I readded it and it's at this point it takes ages and the delays begin.  I've checked in `environment.rb` and all that's in there is:

```
# Load the rails application
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the rails application
Neiltongesite::Application.initialize!
```

Where should I look now in order to track down this delay?

What I want to find out is what it's doing in this time?  Is there a way to get more output?

Comment: Are you using volumes to mount your code? They are notoriously slow, especially when the app has a lot of files. Since Rails preloads the app, this is the first thing I would investigate.

Comment: @jdno I've added my docker-compose.yml file above. What do you think?  I'm not really a Docker expert, very very beginner so not sure where to look.

Comment: @jdno Updated my OP with more details

Comment: Remove the `volume` directive, rebuild the image, run a command and see if that makes a difference. If it does, the volume is the bottleneck. Otherwise, something else is going on...